# Is there a built in program in any of the top EDA software to ease production of Technical Publications?

Tags: cad, eda

I have been assigned to design a PCB and now I have to create Technical Documentation for in-house use. I tried googling this information but it shows the documentation for the software which is not what I was asking for. Software like Siemens Solid Edge have built in support to create technical documentation. Do any EDA software also have this option?